# How to redirect the log text of RS-232 terminal on SSH terminal

Tags: linux, redirect, ssh

My board has RS-232, Ethernet, and the O/S is Fedora 21 Linux. I run my program with RS-232 terminal. So the log from the program shows on the terminal.
After that, I would like to look the log at remote site with SSH terminal.
As far as I know, there was a utility called "setconsole" but I cannot find in it in the Fedora 21. If you know the proper method, please let me know that.

Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: OK, I will move this to  Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. Thank you.